# HyperV - Shrink disk size and error with boot

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, gparted

I have VM with Ubuntu and 125GB partition, for now this OS is using about 15GB. I need to reduce size to 42GB. I have boot with Gparted, resize this partition and boot from vhdx, then I have error from initramfs that cant load root files and cant find specyfic UUID. For now I have back to my backup but I need to find fix and reduce size. Can you help?
Ubuntu version 18.04.6 LTS
I have download gparted iso, add it to hyper-v machine to dvdrom and change prior of boot to dvd first, then run into gparted, shrink, save and this operation was ok, no errors. Then change boot to vhdx file

Maybe shrink from live cd with ubuntu? lsblk from runing VM

loop0    7:0    0   548K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/103

loop1    7:1    0   548K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/106

loop2    7:2    0 110,6M  1 loop /snap/core/12834

loop3    7:3    0  61,9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1405

loop4    7:4    0  65,2M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519

loop5    7:5    0 248,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99

loop6    7:6    0   704K  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/761

loop7    7:7    0   2,6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/920

loop8    7:8    0   2,5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/174

loop9    7:9    0 164,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161

loop10   7:10   0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5

loop11   7:11   0   704K  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/741

loop12   7:12   0  61,9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1376

loop13   7:13   0 111,6M  1 loop /snap/core/12941

loop14   7:14   0   2,5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/884

loop15   7:15   0  55,5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2284

loop16   7:16   0 247,9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/87

loop17   7:17   0   2,5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/169

loop18   7:18   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77

loop19   7:19   0 162,9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145

loop20   7:20   0  65,1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515

loop21   7:21   0  55,5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2344

loop22   7:22   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72

sda      8:0    0   127G  0 disk

├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi

└─sda2   8:2    0 126,5G  0 part /

sr0     11:0    1   444M  0 rom  /media/pramed/GParted-live

have create second machine, run gparted, shrink dev/sda2, run into ubuntu normally without error to 42GB partition. Then when I want to shrink vhdx file from HyperV manager  to 42GB from 125 like -> vm machine -> edit disk -> shrink size then I have error (after shrink). First run Grub, when choose Ubuntu then have logo hyperv for a few minutes and then
"gave up waiting for root file system device.

- boot args
- check rootdelay
- missing modules
  Alert UUID = number doesnt not exist. Dropping to shell "

Comment: Hello. Any and all questions need to start with what version of Ubuntu being used.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the output from `lsblk`. It sounds like you did the right things. Can you explain how you ran GParted. Did you boot the GParted iso? If so there would be nothing different about booting the Ubuntu live cd image.

Comment: Sory, version 18.04.6 LTS
lsblk from running VM

Comment: Presumably you booted the GParted live image. If so I would just try again but make sure you only touch sda2. Make a detailed list of each step you take so if it doesn’t work you can give us the detail to hopefully identify what you did wrong. If you have an Ubuntu live cd there would be no harm in using that instead in case your GParted live cd is faulty

Comment: ok, I will try later to shrink it with live cd

Comment: @PonJar I have create second machine and Update my first post

Comment: Looks like you have a hyperV issue, not an Ubuntu issue. You should probably seek help for that on a hyperV forum. However it looks like this kind of problem can be solved by cloning the vhdx file to a new file. I doubt that is the official way to do it though